# confusion matrix for 2 classes

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, model-evaluation, confusion-matrix

I have a file containing some sentences. Each sentence belongs to a specific class. There are 2 classes,

- "passion"
- "salty".

I classified them with Naive bayes algorithm and now I have to calculate precision and recall.
My question now is, if I want to make confusion matrix, should I first make one for "passion" group and then one for "salty" group (have 2 confusion matrices)?
If so, then how should I calculate precision and recall from these 2 matrices?

Answer (score 1):

> My question now is, if I want to make confusion matrix, should I first
>   make one for "passion" group and then one for "salty" group (have 2
>   confusion matrices)?

You misunderstand what a confusion matrix is.

A confusion matrix for a problem with a number of C classes is a C x C square matrix. Usually the horizontal margin represents the true classes, while the vertical margin represents the predicted classes, however this is sometimes exchanged.

[image]

Into this we fill in the number of instances that our classifier correctly predicted as class A (top left), wrongly predicted as class A (top right), wrongly predicted as class B (bottom left) and correctly predicted as class B (bottom right). This easily extends to problems with more than 2 classes, containing one correct prediction per row but more incorrect ones.

In your case, A and B can be replaced with 'passion' and 'salty'. The calculation of [recall and precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) is fairly straightforward then.

$$\mathrm{Precision}(A) = \frac{\#True A}{\#True A + \#False A}$$
$$\mathrm{Recall}(A) = \frac{\#True A}{\#True A + \#False B} $$

Answer (score -1):

You mean passion can take values (yes/no) and salty can take values (yes/no)? if that's the case, you have four classes, not two. That would result in a 4x4 confusion matrix.

Otherwise, I cannot understand your request.

(I would have commented this post, but I don't have enough reputation, hence I'm posting a full response, you can comment this post if you feel like providing more information).

Comment: No. I have a classifier which has a 2 classes. Now I have to calcualte precision and recall. and I don't know how?

Comment: Then you are already set to use a confusion matrix, since the classes are two. Call salty the "P" and passion the "N", and see  how [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) constructs a confusion matrix for two classes.

Comment: I read them all before. My question is: should make just 1 matrix or 2 (for each class separately), and then have an average of them?

Comment: No, just one confusion matrix. There is all the information you need to compute each statistics for the two classes.

Comment: would you please have a look at the link below:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40773898/make-a-confusion-matrix-for-a-classifier-with-2-classes